# What's the most efficient way to find paired values in text documents

Tags: coldfusion

Given the following text:

```
<Cfsavecontent variable="testString">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</Cfsavecontent>
```

And given the following array:

```
<Cfset pairs = [['ipsum','/bla'],['nisi','/alb']]>
```

How can i replace the first array item and replace them with the second array item in the text.

Output should be:
Lorem **/bla** dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris **/alb** ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

I could do a simple cfloop and search for the array items one by one but this is not very efficient. Is there a better way to deal with this issue.

This is a very simple example. The actual array would contain 500+ keywords that need to be searched and replaced in about 20.000+ text documents.

Comment: I would use the loop that you have already thought of.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing isn't too bad since you can also easily match substrings. If you only need to replace words enclosed by spaces, consider iterating over each word and match against a hash map of the pairs to replace.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="testString">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
</cfsavecontent>

<!--- case insensitive: use a case ignoring ColdFusion struct --->
<cfset pairs = {
    "ipsum": "/bla",
    "nisi":  "/alb"
}>

<!--- case sensitive: use a case aware Java HashMap --->
<!---
    <cfset pairs = createObject("java", "java.util.HashMap").init()>
    <cfset pairs.put("ipsum", "/bla")>
    <cfset pairs.put("nisi",  "/alb")>
--->

<cfset words     = listToArray(testString, " ")>
<cfset wordCount = arrayLen(words)>

<cfloop from="1" to="#wordCount#" index="i">
    <cfif structKeyExists(pairs, words[i])>
        <cfset words[i] = pairs[ words[i] ]>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>

<cfset replacedTestString = arrayToList(words, " ")>

<cfoutput>#replacedTestString#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: "If you only need to replace words enclosed by spaces". This is not the case. There is a solution for this though, https://cflib.org/udf/RESplit (by Raymond Camden). However with reSplit the performance of your suggestion is much slower then a simple loop which iterates and replaces each pair of keywords. 1+ for the suggestion.